# How to make texture coordinates follow curvature of mesh

Tags: uv

I'm making this shader where I use generated and object coordinates to create these yellow lines made using gradient and wave textures. 
I want to know if there is a way to bend the texture coordinates so that the lines follow the curvature of the mesh

[image: lines keep going straight]

this mesh is made with an arrayed plane and curve modifier.
All elements of this road are done in the shader editor.

Comment: if the mesh is made with array and curve, the texture should follow... maybe share your file (with image packed within): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Follow Active Quads or Reset should be very handy if your road is made up of quads. This will give each quad a tile, which should be seamless if your texture is also seamless.