# Make tiled texture bend with object

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders

I'm working on a road model. I managed to make the road texture tile, so I wouldn't have to manually modify the UV mapping each time I extrude or stretch a road.

Note: The road texture is a square seamless image, so is the pavement. The pavement and the road are two different material but their shader nodes are identical at the moment.

[image]

How would I make the road texture rotate with the road faces?

[image]

Comment: don't use object, use uv as coordinates. Create a single road segment, and create the UV map for it. Create a curve that will be the path for the road Then use an array modifier on the road segment and curve modifier that uses the curve to guide the array. Read:  [Create a road along large terrain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/create-a-road-along-large-terrain/7594#7594)

Comment: Alternatively https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69115/how-to-curve-road-without-array-modifier

Comment: as Susu says, use the Texture Coordinate UV output, then you can unwrap with Follow Active Quads option so that the UV is straight

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155591/how-to-make-texture-coordinates-follow-curvature-of-mesh